# How to join to different schema using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I have 2 schema named 'classSchema' and 'sectionSchema' as follows:

```
let classSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  className: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  capacity: {
      type: Number
  }
});
```

and

```
let sectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sectionName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  strength: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  ofClass: {
      type: Mongoose.Schema.type.ObjectId,
  }
});
```

I want to create a Class of student when classSchema is used and a section of that class. For example: I want to create a class 'X' using classSchema and then add sections to it like 'X-A', 'X-B', 'X-C', etc. using sectionSchema. I want to give a reference of class create to the section while creating section. How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like instead of "ofClass" in sectionSchema, u want sectionSchema's ObjectId  referred in classSchema, and store them in an array. Something like,

```
let classSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  className: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  capacity: {
      type: Number
  },
sections:[mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
});
```

And to join then u can use mongoose [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), [find](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiX3Z2247zxAhVbAXIKHSrDDVwQFjAAegQIBhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.com%2Fmanual%2Freference%2Fmethod%2Fdb.collection.find%2F&usg=AOvVaw170rvJ1SkSRC-Ki4DCNqmP) or [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)